# Decimals in X-axis using GoogleVis line chart

Tags: r, dplyr, google-visualization, linechart, googlevis

I am trying to plot a simple line graph with R package GoogleVis. In my plot, my x-axis is an "year" variable. So, when I plot using year as "double", the plot shows decimals that does not exist in data, as follows:

[image]

Then I tried to use mutate and transform year to factor. So, I solved the "decimals" issue, but I got some white spaces in the graph =| , as follows:
[image]

Here is a reproducible code:

```R
library(dplyr)
library(googleVis)

   # Simple data
   df <- tribble(
     ~year, ~value,
     2014,   15,
     2015,   18,
     2016,   14,
     2017,   25
   )

   # X axis with decimals
   df %>% gvisLineChart() %>% plot()

   # X axis with white spaces
   df %>% mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>% gvisLineChart() %>% plot()
```

Anyone knows how to help me? I would like to keep using the same package (googleVis), and I do not want "decimals" neither "white spaces" in x-axis.

Thanks in advance.
Wlademir.

**EDITED**

Code after comments:
`df %>% gvisLineChart(., options = list(hAxis = "{format: '0', ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)}")) %>% plot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove the decimals, use the following configuration option when drawing the chart.

```
hAxis: {
  format: '0'
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["year", "value"],
    [2014,  15],
    [2015,  18],
    [2016,  14],
    [2017,  25],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: '0'
    },
    height: 288,
    vAxis: {
      format: '0',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 10,
        max: 30
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

however, this can sometimes cause the labels to repeat.
although the decimal place is not shown,
the chart still uses values such as --> `2014.0, 2014.5, 2015.0, 2015.5`.
this results in repeated labels --> `2014, 2014, 2015, 2015`

to ensure the labels are not repeated, you can use the `ticks` option.
`ticks` is an array of values to be used on the axis.

```
hAxis: {
  format: '0',
  ticks: [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
}
```

there is also a data table method that could build this array dynamically --> `getDistinctValues(columnIndex)`

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["year", "value"],
    [2014,  15],
    [2015,  18],
    [2016,  14],
    [2017,  25],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: '0',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    },
    height: 288,
    vAxis: {
      format: '0',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 10,
        max: 30
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

note: the white space is a result of converting the year numbers to strings,
as seen in the following snippet.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["year", "value"],
    ['2014',  15],
    ['2015',  18],
    ['2016',  14],
    ['2017',  25],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 288,
    vAxis: {
      format: '0',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 10,
        max: 30
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

strings on the axis result in a *discrete* axis,
numbers a *continuous* axis.

the `format` and `ticks` options are not supported by *discrete* axis'...

Comment: Great solution!! Yes, it works with R, because the googleVis package allows me to add some options. The code was added in the question. Thanks.